# Installing on a new hard drive

Tags: installation

How do I install Ubuntu on a new drive with a downloaded version 13.10 on a dvd? The file is a zip, do I unzip it the the dvd? I have been able to install Ubuntu on a pc with an OS but having trouble with a new hard drive.

Comment: First of all, the file is not a "zip" but a "iso" if it's not a ISO, then you downloaded something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create a bootable usb drive from the downloaded image or burn it to a dvd.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Once you've done that, boot from your chosen medium and install to the target drive.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall