# How to install Ubuntu on new hardrive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I purchased a new hard drive and I want to install Ubuntu 16 on it. I do not want to dual boot with windows I just want to install Ubuntu. I already have a boot CD with Ubuntu on it. When I tried to use the boot disk and install Ubuntu on my new hard drive it didn't work. I hooked up the new hard drive to my windows computer and I can see that all the space is still unallocated. I thought the install would partition the drive as needed. Do I need to partition the new drive myself for an Ubuntu install and if so how? I have installed Ubuntu before on an old Windows drive and it worked fine. It just erased everything and did the install.

Also, I have an Intel i7 processor and the iso says it's for AMD. I thought that it should still work but maybe that's a factor.

I know that there are similar question but they don't seem to address the particular issue I am having:

[Installing ubuntu on new hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439298/installing-ubuntu-on-new-hard-drive)

[Installing on a new hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365438/installing-on-a-new-hard-drive)

[How can I install Ubuntu on an external hardrive from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418397/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-external-hardrive-from-windows)

And i have already read [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

If that had solved my issue i wouldn't be asking the question.

NOTE: When I tried to intall ubuntu I used the boot CD and selected install. Then it displayed the image attached and was stuck there for over 24 hours. I ended up just shutting it of. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C9Jx.png)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#AMD64 ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"When I tried to use the boot disk and install Ubuntu on my new hard drive **it didn't work**."_? When I insert an Ubuntu DVD and boot from it, I get asked "_Install_ or _Just try_"? What do you get instead?

Comment: I got the same thing. I selected install. Then it displayed a purpleish looking display with the word ubuntu in the middle. It stayed like that for over 24 hours.

Comment: What brand/model system? And what video/card/chip. Some need boot parameters. UEFI or BIOS system? Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  If video issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I have and MSI GE62 7rd Apache computer that I replaced the harddrive on with the one i just bought and am trying to install ubuntu on. The hard drive currently has no OS on it.
I have UEFI.

Comment: For graphics it's a GeForce GTX 1050

Comment: amd64 just means 64-bit, FYI, that's not the issue. Please add the hardware details and other clarifications from comments to your question. It looks to me like the "boot disc" or the download or the method of creating it was faulty, or it doesn't like your UEFI settings. Perhaps see [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](//askubuntu.com/q/674441)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really confusing, if i understand correctly, you want to remove windows, and install ubuntu, but you also have a new harddrive and that wasn't formatted correctly for the install. Also, i don't think there's an iso for amd. The installation iso works for both amd and intel, but you have to look if it's 32bit or 64 bit.
Are you trying to install ubuntu from inside windows, or are you booting from the install cd?
if you just normally boot from the install cd, you should just be able to select your windows drive and format it, and then install right onto that drive...
you don't have to manually do the partitioning, it will give you the option to do so, but that's for advanced users.

Comment: I said that i purchased a new hard drive. And I want to install Ubuntu on it. I am not trying to do this from windows. I simply have another computer with windows on it. I hooked up the new hard drive to my windows computer so i can  use diskmgmt to see if all the space was unallocated. The iso i download is "ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso"

Comment: i'm assuming that the drive was formatted to ext3 or ext4, which windows does not recognize. so windows will indeed say that the space is unallocated. was the grub bootloader also installed on that same drive?